# Why is is the dative "den" used in "Sieh den Tatsachen ins Gesicht"?

Tags: declension, standard-german

I'm pretty sure the accusative is used with sehen as in "ich sehe dich". So why do we use the dative form for the plural definite article in this sentence? Am I missing something?

Comment: "Ich sehe dich" Aber: "Ich sehe dir in's Gesicht"

Comment: *Tatsachen* is plural, so there is actually no choice: if you need a definite article, it has for accusative to be *den*.

Comment: @maio290: No, accusative would be *die Tatsachen*.

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to distinguish: _Er fasste sie an den Arm / Er fasste ihr an den Arm_: Both are correct, but the meaning is slightly different. In '... fasste sie an den Arm' the contact is acceptable and accepted, whereas in 'fasste ihr ...' this might be in doubt (cf. 'er fasste ihr an die Brust'). Similarly, you can say 'ich fasste mich / mir an die Stirn'. For me the dative 'dir' in 'dir ins Gesicht' means that there is a mutual understanding, otherwise this would be intrusive or even aggressive. But there is no choice, it has to be 'dir' in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addition to RHa's answer please note the following:

> I'm pretty sure the accusative is used with *sehen* ...

This is correct however there is also the possibility to use the word "*sehen*" with a direction instead of an object:

> Ich sehe nach unten. (I look downwards.)
>   Ich sehe in den Spiegel. (I look in the mirror.)
>   ...

The expression "*jemandem ins Gesicht sehen*" is formed of this variant of "*sehen*": "*Ins Gesicht*" is a direction, not an object.

The second thing you should note is that in German language many expressions are formed by adding a *dative* to another expression:

> Etwas wegnehmen <-> Jemandem etwas wegnehmen
>   Die Haare waschen <-> Jemandem/Sich die Haare waschen
>   ...
>   Ins Gesicht sehen <-> Jemandem ins Gesicht sehen

Answer (score 4):

"To look into someone's face" = "Jemandem[Dat.] ins Gesicht sehen"

In the case of “Sieh den Tatsachen ins Gesicht” you don't look into a person's face but into the face of the facts (metaphorically).

Comment: Cf. 'Ich schau dir in die Augen, Kleines'. Oder: 'Sie sah ihm genau auf den Mund und verstand so das meiste, da er langsam und überdeutlich sprach.' It is a sort of part-of-the-body-dative, which is more common than the possessive article in such cases.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Was ist denn ein "part-of-the-body-dative"? Wo ist das Körperteil bei "Ich brach der Gabel einen Zinken ab"? Ist "ihm ins Gesicht sehen" nicht einfach ein ganz gewöhnlicher Allerweltsdativ?

Comment: @Fred Bob: Es ist insofern ein part-of-the-body-Dativ, da es sich durch ein Possessivpronomen ersetzen lässt: 'sie sah in sein Gesicht'. Metaphorisch gilt das sogar für die Gabel, hier arbeitet man eher mit Attribut: (?) ich brach ihren (rechten) Zinken ab > ich brach den rechten Zinken (von) der Gabel ab. Da eine Gabel kein Mensch ist, ist wäre der Satz mit Dativ/Possessiv sagen wir mal ungewöhnlich. Diese Art Dative gibt's im Deutschen viel; _jm den Kopf waschen / die Ohren langziehen..._ Der Allerweltsdativ ist eine etwas empfangende Person: _Hilf mir. Gib ihm das zurück. Ich erklär's dir._